# Does the browser have cookies enabled?

Tags: cookies

Is there a standard technique for an ASP.NET application to check if a client's browser 
enables/supports cookies?

I'd appreciate any solution - even a less common one, as long as it's elegant enough.

10x!

Answer (score 2):

Well, the only way to check it is to try to set a cookie, then in the next request check if the browser sent it back.